# Problema ao importar model

Tags: django, importação, serialização

Olá, não estou conseguindo fazer o `import` deste model

tenho o model:

```
class Contrato(models.Model):
```

dentro de models.py

e dentro de meu serializers.py preciso fazer o import

```
from models import Contrato
```

nem

```
from apps.contratos.models import Contrato
```

Nem nada funciona, em outros apps funciona tranquilamente.

Comment: Passa apenas app e model `from myapp.models import Contrato`

Comment: Verifique seu `PYTHONPATH`, o caminho de importação precisa ser encontrado relativo a ele. Se a pasta `apps` está no PYTHONPATH, então `from contratos.models import Contrato` deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava ocorrendo um loop de importação, estavam se importando mutuamente. Resolvido, apenas retirei a importação de um dos arquivos e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu arquivo serializer estiver no mesmo módulo que o seu model, uma maneira de importar seria: `from .models import Contrato`

Answer (score 0):

O texto da pergunta poderia ser um pouco mais completo e fornecer o `traceback` do erro. No entanto, sem saber a estrutura do projecto, o problema poderá estar no facto de o directorio onde se encontram ambos esses ficheiros não conter o ficheiro `__init__.py` ( [veja porquê](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) ).

Se esse ficheiro estiver presente, a seguinte linha deverá ser sufeciente para importar com sucesso:

```
from .models import Contrato
```